# Linear Regression - Predict ŷ

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, predict

I'm trying to plot a scatter plot of the values of actual sales (y) and predicted sales (ŷ).

I have imported the csv file and currently the codes I have for the linear regression model is:

```
result = smf.ols('sales ~ discount + holiday + product', data=data).fit()
print(result.summary())
```

Since, I only have the actual sales values, how do I find the predicted sales (ŷ) values to plot the scatter plot? I have tried researching and found `lm.predict()` and `result.predict()`. Is there a difference? `lm = LinearRegression()`
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by ‚predicted sales‘. Why do you make a regression if you do not consider it to be the prediction?

Comment: Predicted sales based on all the x variables in the regression model so that I can plot the actual sales and predicted sales on a scatter plot.

Comment: I dont really understand the downvotes here. You can get your predicted values by calling result.predict(), which will be your yhat values

Comment: @Simon The question leaves it entirely unclear what problem there actually is. The problem itself is trivial and the two variants of ‚predict‘ are not qualified - it is pretty difficult to tell the difference without knowing what the things even are.

Answer (score 1):

Without data it is hard to help, but I guess you have `X` and `y` from dataset because you want to perform linear regression. You can split data into training and test set using `scikit-learn`:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3)
```

Then you need to fit linear regression to the training set:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and afterwards predict test set results:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Finally, you can plot your test or training results:

```
# Visualising the Training set results
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Discount vs Sales (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Discount percentage')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.show()

# Visualising the Test set results
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Discount vs Sales (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Discount percentage')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.show()
```

(In this scenario we want to predict how many Sales will be if we set specific value of e.g. Discount percentage). If you have more than one `X` parameter, things are more complicated and you will need to use dummy variables, perform statistical analysis etc..